# ExceptionInInitializerError in GLES.createCapabilities()

Tags: java, opengl-es, lwjgl

I'm trying to implement a game engine with lwjgl in a fashion that it would     suit Android devices. As a consequence I have to use `opengles`. 
So I tried the [window creation](https://github.com/lwjglgamedev/lwjglbook/blob/master/chapter02/src/main/java/org/lwjglb/engine/Window.java) which worked, I thought it's time to swap the `opengl` stuff to `opengles`.
However, on the line

```
GLES.createCapabilities();
```

I get an `ExceptionInInitializerError`:

> Exception in thread "GAME_LOOP_THREAD"
>       java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at engine.Window.init(Window.java:92)

Here is my `Window` class, where the exception is thrown:

```
package engine;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengles.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengles.GLES20.GL_FALSE;
import static org.lwjgl.opengles.GLES20.GL_TRUE;
import static org.lwjgl.opengles.GLES20.glClearColor;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;

public class Window {

    private final String title;

    private int width;

    private int height;

    private long windowHandle;

    private boolean resized;

    private boolean vSync;

    public Window(String title, int width, int height, boolean vSync) {
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.vSync = vSync;
        this.resized = false;
    }

    public void init() {
        // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
        // will print the error message in System.err.
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before             doing this.
        if (!glfwInit()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        }

        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints     are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE); // the window will stay         hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE); // the window will be     resizable
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

        // Create the window
        windowHandle = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL,     NULL);
        if (windowHandle == NULL) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
        }

        // Setup resize callback
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(windowHandle, (window, width,     height) -> {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.setResized(true);
        });

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(windowHandle, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect     this in the rendering loop
            }
        });

        // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        // Center our window
        glfwSetWindowPos(
                windowHandle,
                (vidmode.width() - width) / 2,
                (vidmode.height() - height) / 2
        );

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowHandle);

        if (isvSync()) {
            // Enable v-sync
            glfwSwapInterval(1);
        }

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(windowHandle);

        GLES.createCapabilities();

        // Set the clear color
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    public void setClearColor(float r, float g, float b, float a) {
        glClearColor(r, g, b, a);
    }

    public boolean isKeyPressed(int keyCode) {
        return glfwGetKey(windowHandle, keyCode) == GLFW_PRESS;
    }

    public boolean windowShouldClose() {
        return glfwWindowShouldClose(windowHandle);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public boolean isResized() {
        return resized;
    }

    public void setResized(boolean resized) {
        this.resized = resized;
    }

    public boolean isvSync() {
        return vSync;
    }

    public void setvSync(boolean vSync) {
        this.vSync = vSync;
    }

    public void update() {
        glfwSwapBuffers(windowHandle);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`, not a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: Right, I tinkered with a lot and I might have posted an out of date exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537585/there-is-no-opengl-es-context-current-in-the-current-thread-lwjgl-using-opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537585/there-is-no-opengl-es-context-current-in-the-current-thread-lwjgl-using-opengl)